onPress in react native map function some case doesn't work
My parent Comments components have a single comment.
This is Comments - part of the code
{sort === 'recent' &&
  sortByRecent.length > 0 &&
  sortByRecent.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <CommentUnit
      gradeUI={props.gradeUI}
      key={`${item.id}commentOf${props.commentType}Recent`}
      item={item}
      writable={props.writable}
      handlePressCommentInputButton={handlePressCommentInputButton}
      handleCollapse={handleCollapse}
      handleMoveProfile={props.handleMoveProfile}
      getRecomment={() => {
        props.commentType === 'notice' && handleAPI11_16(item.id);
        props.commentType === 'gathering-feed' &&
          handleAPI10_14(item.id);
        props.commentType === 'personal-feed' &&
          handle3_14(item.id);
        props.commentType === 'schedule' && handleAPI9_24(item.id);
      }}
      commentType={props.commentType}
    />
  );
})}

And here is SingleComments - part of the code
<CustomPressable
  style={[styles.flexDirectionRow]}
  onPress={moveProfile}>
  <View style={[styles.authorImageWrapper, {borderWidth: 1}]}>
    <FastImage
      style={[styles.imageSize, styles.circleImageSize]}
      source={item.author.image ? {uri: item.author.image} : IMAGE.user}
    />
    {gradeUI &&
      item.author.grade != undefined &&
      item.author.grade != '일반' && (
        <View style={styles.stickerImageWrapper}>
          <FastImage
            style={styles.circleImageSize}
            source={
              item.author.grade === '모임장'
                ? IMAGE.il_dotCrownBadge
                : item.author.grade === '정회원'
                ? IMAGE.il_starBadge
                : IMAGE.il_crownBadge
            }
          />
        </View>
      )}
  </View>
  <Text style={[styles.authorNicknameText, {borderWidth: 1}]}>
    {item.author.nickname}
    {item.author.id}
  </Text>
</CustomPressable>

I created logic that moves to the profile when the onPress function is pressed, but onPress itself is not called in some components.
This is an example of an issue.

When you press the first one, the moveProfile function is executed, but the second one has no response.
It is irregular and sometimes everything works fine.

whats the problem..?
